Fitted Line (through midpoints of 30 min candle sticks)
I am trying to draw a fitted (horizontal) line through the midpoints of the 30 min candlestick BODIES within the Regular Trading Hours, so this will be 13x 30 min Candles. Therefore, the horizontal fitted line should statistically represent the 13x midpoints.  Any help or links with additional information are highly appreciated.
I read about the linear regression function in pinescript, but not sure if this is the right path to follow since the examples seemed quite different.
